# How auto prepend post's category to url?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, url-routing

In Yii2 I have blog with articles, each one has 1 category. Rules are so:

```
'rules' => [
    '<category_slug>/<article_slug>' => 'article/view',
],
```

controller:

```
public function actionView($category_slug, $article_slug)
{
    ...
}
```

Categories are stored in `params.php`:

```
<?php
return [
    'categories' => [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'First category',
            'slug' => 'first_category',
        ],
        ...
    ],
];
```

Url to article:

```
Url::to(['article/view', 'category_slug' => $model->category_slug, 'article_slug' => $model->article_slug])
```

**Question:** Is it possible to auto prepend category slug to `Url::to`? I mean, you need only make `Url::to` with `article_slug` param. I suppose best solution will be to change url rules somehow, but how exactly?

```
'rules' => [
    '<Yii::$app->MyFunction->GetCategorySlugByArcticleId(..)>/<article_slug>' => 'article/view',
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be an easy one.

### Option one: extend the Url-Helper

Simply extend the [Url-Helper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-url.html) as follows:

```
class MyUrl extends \yii\helpers\Url
{

    //extending regular `to`-method
    public static function to($url = '', $scheme = false)
    {
        //check if url needs completion and meets preconditions
        if (is_array($url) && strcasecmp($url[0], 'article/view') === 0 && isset($url['article_slug']) && !isset($url['category_slug'])) {
            //add category slug if missing...assuming you have a relation from article to category and category having a property `slug`
            $url['category_slug'] = $article->category->slug;
        }
        
        return parent::to($url, $scheme);
    }

    //...or custom method for your case which is even more convenient
    public static function toArticle($article, $scheme=false)
    {
        //article could be an article model itself or an id
        $articleModel = $article instanceof Article ? $article : Article::findOne($article);
        return parent::to([
            'article/view',
            'article_slug'=>$articleModel->slug,
            'category_slug'=>$articleModel->category->slug,
        ], $scheme);
    }

}
```

All you have to do now is use that class instead of the regular `Url`-helper!

### Option two: add a method within your article model

Simply add a method as follows:

```
class Article extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    //...

    public function link($scheme=false)
    {
        return Url::to([
            'article/view',
            'article_slug'=>$this->slug,
            'category_slug'=>$this->category->slug,
        ], $scheme);
    }

    //...
}
```

Let me know if you need more info!

Comment: Great! Is it possible to do the same job without creating new class? Like `Url::toArticle(...)`. Question means where can I simply put `toArticle` function?

Comment: You could also wrap this within your Article-model. I extended my answer above!